# Get local PDF page height - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I have a pdf stored locally in an iphone. I want to get the height of that pdf having the path. I've tried:

```
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.documentPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(CFBridgingRetain(pdfUrl));
float width = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 0), kCGPDFMediaBox).size.width;
float height = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 0), kCGPDFMediaBox).size.height;
```

But the document is null, and I don't know any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, I hope it helps you :)

```
// fileName is the PDF path
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"__PDF_PATH"];

// Convert NSData to CFDataRef
CFDataRef thePDFdata = (__bridge CFDataRef)pdfData;

// Create CGDataProviderRef object from data
CGDataProviderRef providerObj = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(thePDFdata);

// Create the PDF using provider object
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(providerObj);

// Get the first page of the PDF
CGPDFPageRef pdfPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);

// Get the rect object from page 1
CGRect pdfPageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);

float width = pdfPageRect.size.width;
float height = pdfPageRect.size.height;

NSLog(@"WIDTH: %f HEIGHT: %f", width, height);
```